# How do you test your webapps on social network inapp browsers on mobile?

Tags: testing, browser, web-applications, tiktok

My goal is to use my webapp as ad target on the social network marketing campaign.

Facebook business has a feature to send an url to the mobile to test it.

I am able to test on Snapchat by sending me the url.

How to test on TikTok ? TikTok Business is not available on mobile.

Answer (score 1):

For TikTok, a first solution I found is to scroll TikToks until I find an ad one with a link to a webpage, then I just go to the footer and click on the facebook link. From Facebook, I can go to my wall to open the web page I want.